# Adding restriction to a SQL Server stored procedure script

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, restriction

How I can add to these 2 scripts below a restriction, so it wont allow creating a hero with less than 3 characters in its name or when changing the name of the hero it wont allow less than 3 characters as well?

Currently everyone can create a hero with name: 1 or change their name  .. basically all possible variations are available. I want to restrict it to minimum 3 characters name.

- SQL Server stored procedure script [creating a hero]: http://pastebin.com/pg9zt3Ps
- SQL Server stored procedure script [changing a hero name]: http://pastebin.com/TB3ZzvyP

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2005 / 64 bit

Will be much appreciated.

Kind Regards.

Comment: What database system you're using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2005  ... Sorry, I've forgot to mention it in my first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the start of your `CREATE_NEW_CHAR` procedure, you could do this...

```
IF LEN(LTRIM(@CharID)) < 3  -- LEN() does an RTRIM()
BEGIN
  SET @nRet = 7
  RETURN
END
```

The same in the `CHANGE_NEW_ID` procedure, but use `IF LEN(LTRIM(@NewCharID)) < 3` instead.

The calling application is probably already checking the value of `@nRet` after executing the procedure. Hopefully it will give a generic error message if `@nRet!=0`. But, you may want to enhance that code, so that if `@nRet=7` it can show a specific error message about the name entered being too short.

I've updated Pastebin also: [`CREATE_NEW_CHAR`](http://pastebin.com/z2Je8xkb) & [`CHANGE_NEW_ID`](http://pastebin.com/R4HqMA5b)

Comment: Can't I use these lines in my script that are already there or I must add the one you suggested ? ... `SET @x = 1` and `WHILE (@x <= LEN(@CharID))` ?

Comment: I think you want to check the length before entering the `WHILE` loop to validate the individual characters.

Comment: It doesnt matter where exactly it will do the check .. the only thing that matters is when they enter less than 3 characters and click the button to create the hero, so the script will restrict them and wont create it until they use 3 or more characters and not less than 3. So, finally could you please upload to pastebin the both edited scripts with the restriction, would be much appreciated since I dont want to mess up something .. because i cant make a db backup right now and to be safe. Once again will appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Yes, so if you put the above `IF` before the `WHILE` loop, it will exit the procedure immediately when the name is not long enough. If you want to tell the user the reason why it didn't work, check the value of `nRet`.

Comment: Should I remove the `WHILE (@x <= LEN(@CharID))` line from the current script ?

Comment: Nah, the change is just addition, no modification of existing code. Let me see if I can update pastebin.

Comment: Yeah, there is an option to create new version of the current pastebin posted.

Comment: OK cool, not used Pastebin before, but yeah it was easy ;-) links added to answer.

Comment: I've received an error probably because it was nRet without @ .. I've added it and it executed successfully, right ? Will test now if it works.

Comment: oops yes sorry. fixed pastebin and answer.

Comment: I think it works, and just one last thing how I will be able to change the nret message now ? Because 5 and 7 are for something different. Also, this check you have suggested only restric for characters under 3 characters in the name, not anything other, correctly ?

Comment: In that case .. last thing that I am curious why we should use LTRIM or it's necessary ?

Comment: If the parameter contains leading spaces, they will be included in the output of `LEN()`. If you want to allow leading spaces in the name (I doubt it?) or you are sure the calling app is trimming it, then you don't need it.

Comment: For checking @nRet, can you post the code that does that already?

Comment: Will do post, so to sum it up LTRIM will remove these leading spaces because I dont want to allow them for sure.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29796/discussion-between-davmos-and-nmalko)